# Flask-sqlalchemy `create_all()`, specifying models

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the file with commands, separated from models. The models had executed only after I had imported all the models from `models` to my `starter` file.

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)                      

from models import *                     

try:                                      
    argv = sys.argv[1]                    
    argv == '--run' and app.run()         
    argv == '--create' and db.create_all()
```

But it is pretty ambiguously for me. I walk around Flask-Sqlalchemy source code. I saw:

```
def get_tables_for_bind(self, bind=None):
    """Returns a list of all tables relevant for a bind."""
    result = []
    for table in self.Model.metadata.tables.itervalues():
        if table.info.get('bind_key') == bind:
            result.append(table)
    return result
```

And I understand the `self.Model` is:

```
def make_declarative_base(self):
    """Creates the declarative base."""
    base = declarative_base(cls=Model, name='Model',
                            mapper=signalling_mapper,
                            metaclass=_BoundDeclarativeMeta)
    base.query = _QueryProperty(self)
    return base
```

Do I have more explicit way to specify the models for execution? And how the `self.Model` knows what the tables must be executed (after import)?